# How to access newly created elements by pure js?

Tags: javascript

I made some 'warning' layer to use instead of 'alert()'.

```
code :
warning = document.getElementById('warning'); // This line is what exactly I want to make functional. the code out side of warning(); This line runs before 'elem:div#warning' is made by warning().

function warning() {
a = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.id = 'warning';
a.className= 'warning';
}
```

But I don't know how to access that newly created and added element by javascript.

I think css works fine with newly added elements. But js is not.

I searched google, and found some methods register newly created element automatically using prototype, but it was hard to understand to me...

So, what I trying to do is, access to newly created element 'a' by javascript which executed before that 'a' was created.

I tried this method :

```
if(document.getElementById('warning')) {alert('asdf')};
```

But it was useless...

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: `appendChild()` returns the newly-created element, hence `warning = ...`

Comment: You have created the element using createElement('div'), You need to access it after it has created, use some JS to access it once the Element creation is confirmed.

Comment: did you try to place the `warning = document.getElementById('warning');` inside function?

Comment: your variable "warning" has the same name that your function, not conflicts ? is your var "warning" a "global" variable ?

Comment: yes, I tried insert defining code into function. And it worked. But what I want to make is , work on outside of the function...

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/7bncvhs4/1/), it works for me, did small change.

```
function warning() {
   a = document.createElement('div');
   document.body.appendChild(a);
   a.id = 'warning';
   a.className= 'warning';
}

warning();

warningDiv = document.getElementById('warning');

if(document.getElementById('warning')) {
  alert('warning div on DOM')
};
```